Issue with Jenkins Pipeline script for setting up CI/CD in a Next.js application Body:

I am currently setting up Continuous Integration and Continuous Deployment (CI/CD) for a Next.js application using Jenkins Pipeline. While I have successfully connected my GitHub repository and set up webhooks, I am facing difficulties with writing the JenkinsFile Pipeline script.
My environment consists of Ubuntu 16.04, and I have multiple Next.js applications deployed using PM2 and Apache. Previously, I manually handled updates by navigating to the project directory on the Ubuntu server and executing commands like git pull, npm install, npm run build, and pm2 reload to deploy updates. However, I am looking to remove the downtime during builds and PM2 reloads by integrating Jenkins into my workflow.(I'm not sure it's possible to get rid of downtime.)
Although I have made progress with setting up Jenkins, I am stuck at the part where I need to write the JenkinsFile script.
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("Build") {
            steps {
                sh "npm install"
                sh "npm run build"
            }
        }
        stage("Deploy") {
            steps {
                script {
                    // Unsure how to proceed with the deployment stage
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

In the above JenkinsFile, I encountered the error message: "npm command not found" when attempting to run npm install. (I attempted to install npm on the Jenkins container using apt-get, but I encountered a 'Permission denied' error. Unsure if this approach was correct, and unable to find similar cases, I halted at this point.) Additionally, I am unsure about how to proceed with the deployment stage (Deploy) given my current setup.
I would greatly appreciate any guidance on resolving the npm command not found issue and properly configuring the JenkinsFile.
